# How to display image larger than 10000 px width or height?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have found some problems in displaying images larger than 10000px width or height in spark Image component. Despite of setting maximum width/height or explicit width/height to larger sizes the image is being scaled down to 10000px.

```
<s:Image id="image" source="big.jpg" maxWidth="20000" maxHeight="20000" width="14400" height="10800" x="-9200" y="-8200" />
<s:Label id="debug" />
```

I set these coordinates to be sure I see the bottom right corner of image (it's scaled down proportionally). In debug I'm displaying the mouseX and mouseY of image.

```
protected function application1_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  debug.text = image.mouseX + ", " + image.mouseY;
}
```

Comment: can't you split the image?

Comment: It's something, I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I have found that using BitmapImage component works fine, however it has some limitations. My question about Image component remains valid.

Comment: what are the limitations to `BitmapImage` that don't work for you?

Comment: Mouse events. I solved my problem by using BitmapImage and container which is the event dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` component uses `BitmapImage` internally: `Image.imageDisplay`.

If `BitmapImage` works fine, manually setting `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of `Image.imageDisplay` might fix the bug.

**Added:**

When you manually setting the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of `imageDisplay`, I recommend using a custom Skin to set them. Or they could be set **after** the image is loaded and scaled already.

**Additional Information:**

The default value of `BitmapImage.scaleMode` is `stretch`, but the default value of `Image.scaleMode` is `letterbox`. So, if you see `BitmapImage` works fine but `Image` scales differently, check this property.

Comment: also, if you want to sync `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`, you can extend `Image` class if you prefer, or you may use the data bindings like: `<s:BitmapImage id="imageDisplay" maxWidth="{hostComponent.maxWidth}" ... />` in your custom skin.

Comment: I am happy to hear that :')

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple - check out the documentation: http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Image.html

Maybe I should write it here, as nobody actually reads that docs - 10k is the limit of both width and height for that component.

edit: Are you serious you need image larger than 10k?! Can you imagine how much memory this is? :)

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Which part of documentation you're talking about? Have you tried to run my example?

About your questions. Yes, I am serious and yes I can imagine :)

Comment: Come on man, at the very beginning of the docs there is a small table stating: Maximum size 10000 pixels wide and 10000 pixels high... Make some efforts! :)

Comment: That is the default value of maximum width/height (as it says 'the default characteristic'), and it is also the default of most other components. User can change it anytime.